# How to diagnose Nvidia geforce 8400 gs / directx 9.0c render artifacts

Tags: directx, nvidia

In all of the "u.i." pages of Dangerous Waters 1.04 and Falcon Bms 4.32 I get
thin horizontal bars (see attached image).

They are not in the "main sim window" ("3d" fullscreen )

I'm running Win xp sp3,  DirectX 9. 0c (4.09.0000.0904), on an HP DC5000 / 1gig / and the geforce 8400 gs. I also tried installing older drivers (169.21),(195.62) but the problem remains

The above games, run perfectly on at least 3 other systems I've tried, one was XP, the other two Win7, all geforce cards, a 6600, 9600, and 9800, with the latest nvidia drivers.

Other graphic apps like Blender, iRacing, xplane, ClearviewRC, Orbiter, run perfectly well on this box / card combo

I installed the nvidia perfkit, but it does not seem to be useful for apps without source code

Are there any "black box" directx / nvidia debuggers / tools that I can use to determine where the problem is originating ?

Mike

[Nvidia 8400 gs render artifacts](http://mstram.webfactional.com/webb/dw/dangWaters.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can try PIX which comes with the DirectX SDK, but without sources or symbols, not sure how much you will be able to diagnose.